# accepts_nested_attributes_for practical form use for in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Ruby on Rails 3:

I semi-understand how accepts_nested_attributes_for is *supposed* to work, but I can't figure out a practical way to implement this in a form. For example, if someone wanted to add their most recent locations in their user page:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**location table**

```
location
  -location
  -length_of_stay
  -user_id
```

Any ideas on how I go about implementing this practically in the **user** view `_form.html.erb`? The documentation doesn't talk anything about the view whatsoever.

I tried using the railscast tutorial but it did not work whatsoever -- I believe the cast was made for rails 2.3, but I'm not sure if there's different usage in 3.

Comment: Can you post some code? I used the railscast to implement it in rails 3 and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm really spaced out right now but I'm getting `undefined method 'content'` when I use the tutorial.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Content was a column on the table he had created, so if you are doing it with your own tables this shouldn't apply (if you are saying what I think you are saying - the second after the parameters to the accepts_nested_attributes_for).

Comment: Yup, that was it. I am an idiot. Thanks, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

accepts_nested_attributes need to implement situation when you have some chained models and want to create and edit them in one form.
For example: **Users** and their **Locations**

This is common situation and it's used widely. For example:

```
<%= form_for @user, users_path do |form| %>
 <%= form.text_field :name %>
 <%= form.fields_for :locations do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :location %>
     ...
 <% end %>
<%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You should read: http://api.rubyonrails.org/ about ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods