# How can i use a one form/table for multiple MVC's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cant really wrap my head around how to do this since I'm new at RoR.I have a `Price` model which is the only table i want to use for forms. I want to have 2 other MVCs that are `UserData` and `Search`.

The scenario is Users can input Prices and these Prices have 3 places to go. It can be their Data area, Search area or both areas. But the twist is Data area will have my parts on the form like the category of price and same goes with the Search area, that form you can put tags on it.

So how do i set it up so i am using my Prices form for the other 2 MVCs?

EDIT:

`User` has_many `Prices`

`UserData` has_many `Prices` and Category belongs_to `UserData`

`Search` has_many `Prices` and `Tag` belongs_to `Search`

`Price` Form = price name, date, and cost only.

`UserData` + Price Form + `Category` model = price name,date,cost and **category**.

`Search` + Price form + `Tag` Model = price name,date,cost and **tags of price** ( vegetables, candy?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi If you're using rails 3 check `http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance` if older version you should create folder `shared` under your views directory and place there partial `_price_form` and render it on page `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html` - guide on rendering

If your have any connections between models please post its description

now how to have one form for several models 
for better understanding I would advise you to check these 2 railscasts

`http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1`
`http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2`

also `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717421/accepts-nested-attributes-for-practical-form-use-for-in-rails-3` may be helpful

Comment: I added more description in regards to how i want the forms to function for all 3 MVCs to clarify even more. Thanks!

Comment: still not clear) Are there any connections like `has_many` between models?

Comment: if you need sth else or it didn't help you please leave a comment